# Compare multiple columns of a dataframe and store the result in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data which looks like this(I've set 'rule_id' as the index):

```
rule_id  a   b   c  d
50378    2   0   0  5
50402    12  9   6  0
52879    0   4   3  2
```

After using this code:

```
    coeff = df.T

    # compute the coefficients
    for name, s in coeff.items():
        top = 100              # start at 100
        r = []
        for i, v in enumerate(s):
            if v == 0:         # reset to 100 on a 0 value
                top=100
            else:
                top = top/2    # else half the previous value
            r.append(top)
        coeff.loc[:, name] = r # set the whole column in one operation

    # transpose back to have a companion dataframe for df
    coeff = coeff.T

    # build a new column from 2 consecutive ones, using the coeff dataframe
    def build_comp(col1, col2, i):


        conditions = [(df[col1] == 0) & (df[col2] == 0), (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] == 0), (df[col1] == df[col2]),
                      (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] != 0)]

        choices = [np.nan , 100 , coeff[col1] , df[col2]/df[col1]*coeff[col1]+coeff[col1]]

        df['comp{}'.format(i)] = np.select(conditions , choices)

    old = df.columns[0]          # store name of first column

    #Ok, enumerate all the columns (except first one)
    for i, col in enumerate(df.columns[1:], 1):
        build_comp(old, col, i)
        old = col                # keep current column name for next iteration
 # special processing for last comp column
df['comp{}'.format(i+1)] = np.where(df[col] == 0, np.nan, 100)
```

my data looks like this:

```
rule_id  a   b   c  d  comp1  comp2  comp3  comp4
50378    2   0   0  5   100    NaN    NaN    100
50402    12  9   6  0   87.5   41.66  100    NaN
52879    0   4   3  2   NaN    87.5  41.66  100
```

So 'df' here is the dataframe which stores my data which I have mentioned above. 
Look at the first row . According to my code , if two columns are compared and the first column has a non-zero value(2) and the second column has 0 , then 100 should be updated in the new column , which I am able to achieve , if there is comparison between more than one non-zero value (look at row 2) , then the comparison is like this:

```
9/12 *50 +50 = 87.5
```

then

```
6/9 * 25 + 25 = 41.66
```

which I am able to achieve but the third comparison between column 'c' and 'd' which is between value 6 and 0 should be:

```
0/6 *12.5 + 12.5 = 12.5
```

which I am having problem in achieving. So instead of 100 in row 2 comp3 , the value should be 12.5. Same goes for the last row too where values are 4 ,3 and 2

This is the result I want:

```
rule_id  a   b   c  d  comp1  comp2  comp3  comp4
50378    2   0   0  5   100    NaN    NaN    100
50402    12  9   6  0   87.5   41.66  12.5   NaN
52879    0   4   3  2   NaN    87.5  41.66   12.5
```

Comment: Hi, this is quite hard to follow... could you please try to create a minimal example of what is not working as you expect?

Comment: ok , sure. I'll edit my question

Comment: Hi @Joël , I have edited my question , please take a look

Comment: Thanks, it's clearer; could you publish the expected again though?

Comment: I have updated my question as per your comment @Joël.

Comment: Hi @Joël , I have asked a question which is related to this one. Can you take a look please   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870042/update-a-function-in-python-if-first-2-columns-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to participate, here is a contribution to your code, for the definition of the `coeff` matrix, where the computation is performed directly on whole columns.

Initialization:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 0, 0, 5], [12, 9, 6, 0], [0, 4, 3, 2]],
...                    index=[50378, 50402, 52879],
...                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> df 
        a   b   c   d
50378   2   0   0   5
50402   12  9   6   0
52879   0   4   3   2
```

Then computing the coefficients:

```
>>> # taking care of coefficients, using direct computation on columns
>>> coeff2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
>>> top = pd.Series([100]*len(df.index), index=df.index)
>>> for col_name, col in df.iteritems():  # loop over columns
...     eq0 = (col==0)             # boolean serie, identifying rows where content is 0
...     top[eq0] = 100             # where `eq0` is `True`, set 100...
...     top[~eq0] = top[~eq0] / 2  # ... and divide others by 2
...     coeff2[col_name] = top     # assign to output
>>> coeff2
```

Which gives:

```
        a   b   c     d
50378   50  100 100   50
50402   50  25  12.5  100
52879   100 50  25    12.5
```

(For the core of your question, John identified the lack of condition in the function, so no need for me to participate.)

Comment: Hi @Joel , can you join the chat , I have added a code of mine but I am getting an error , I have explained everything in the chat , will you take a look?

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> the third comparison between column 'c' and 'd' which is between value 6 and 0 should be:
>
> ```
> 0/6 *12.5 + 12.5 = 12.5
> ```

But your code says:

> ```
>    conditions = [(df[col1] == 0) & (df[col2] == 0), (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] == 0), (df[col1] == df[col2]),
>                   (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] != 0)]
>
>    choices = [np.nan , 100 , coeff[col1] , df[col2]/df[col1]*coeff[col1]+coeff[col1]]
> ```

Clearly `(6, 0)` satisfies `condition[1]` and therefore produces `100`.  You seem to think it should satisfy `condition[3]` which is that both are non-zero, but `(6, 0)` does not satisfy that condition, and even if it did it would not matter because `condition[1]` is matched first, and `np.select()` chooses the first match.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
    conditions = [(df[col1] == 0) & (df[col2] == 0), (df[col1] == df[col2])]
    choices = [np.nan , coeff[col1]]
    default = df[col2]/df[col1]*coeff[col1]+coeff[col1]

    df['comp{}'.format(i)] = np.select(conditions , choices, default)
```

Comment: Yeah , that's the problem. I don't know how to overcome it

Comment: @vesuvius: I have provided a possible solution now.

Comment: It can work but the problem with default is , if col1 !=0 and col2 ==0 , suppose col1 is 2 and col2 is 0 , then the result would be 0/2 * 50 + 50 which would be 50 but I want 100 in this case. Take a look at the first row of my data

Comment: So if it's `(2, 0)` you want 100 but if it's `(6, 0)` you want the complex formula?  What are the criteria, you need to precisely describe how the `(2, 0)` case is distinguished from the `(6, 0)` case, or you are asking the impossible.

Comment: It's not about (2,0) and (6,0) , it's just that , look at the first row , there is only 1 non-zero value(2) and there is no non-zero value before it but in the second row , the values are 12 9 6 0 , so before 6 there is a non-zero value(9) present , so in that case I need to apply the complex formula. Basically , I want if there is a comparison between non-zero and 0 value , it should first check if the previous column has a non-zero value or not , if it does , then apply the complex formula , otherwise 100

Comment: OK then just pass `col0` as another column to `build_comp()` and add a condition for that.

Comment: Ok , I'll try and get back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194754/discussion-between-vesuvius-and-john-zwinck).