# Update a function in python where first two columns doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have created a function which checks three columns and applies the conditions I have mentioned in the function. I have set first column(col0) as None. This is how my columns look like:

```
rule_id  col0  col1 col2  
50378     2      0    0  
50402    12      9    6  
52879     0      4    3
```

Here 'rule_id' column is the index

This is my code:

```
for i, j, in dframe.groupby('tx_id'):

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(j)

    df = df1.pivot_table(index = 'rule_id' , columns = ['date'], values = 
      'rid_fc', aggfunc = np.sum,  fill_value = 0)

    coeff = df.T

# compute the coefficients
    for name, s in coeff.items():
        top = 100              # start at 100
        r = []
        for i, v in enumerate(s):
            if v == 0:         # reset to 100 on a 0 value
                top=100
            else:
                top = top/2    # else half the previous value
            r.append(top)
        coeff.loc[:, name] = r # set the whole column in one operation

# transpose back to have a companion dataframe for df
    coeff = coeff.T

    def build_comp(col1, col2, i, col0 = None):

        conditions = [(df[col1] == 0) & (df[col2] == 0)  ,(df[col1] == df[col2]) , (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] > df[col2]) , 
                      (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] < df[col2]) ,(df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] == 0)]

        choices = [np.nan , coeff[col1] , df[col2]/df[col1]*coeff[col1],df[col2]/df[col1]* coeff[col1],100]

        condition = [(df[col2] != 0) , (df[col2] == 0)]


        choice = [100 , np.nan]

        if col0 is not None:
            conditions.insert(1, (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] == 0) & (df[col0] != 0))
            choices.insert(1, 25)

            condition.insert(0,(df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] != 0))
            choice.insert(0, 25)

        if col0 is None:
            condition.insert(0,(df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] != 0))
            choice.insert(0, 25)


        df['comp{}'.format(i)] = np.select(conditions , choices , default = np.nan)
        df['comp{}'.format(i+1)] = np.select(condition , choice)


    col_ref = None
    col_prev = df.columns[0]
    for i, col in enumerate(df.columns[1:], 1):
        build_comp(col_prev, col, i, col_ref)
        col_ref = col_prev
        col_prev = col

    if len(df.columns) == 1:
       df['comp1'] = [100] * len(df)
```

'df' is the dataframe which has these columns.There are multiple conditions involved in this function as you can see. I want to add one more , which is both col0 and col1 are None but I don't know how. I tried adding a condition inside `if col0 is None:` like:

```
if col1 is None:
     conditions.insert(0, (df[col2] != 0)
     choices.insert(0, 100)
```

But it's not working. Suppose I have only one column (col2) and both col0 and col1 are not there, then the result should be like this as per my condition:

```
rule_id  col2  comp1
50378     2     100
51183     3     100
```

But comp column is not getting created. If you guys could help me achieve that , I'd greatly appreciate it.

Current code(Edit): After using the code @Joël suggested. I made the alterations. This is the code:

```
def build_comp(col2, i, col0 = None, col1 = None): 

        conditions = [(df[col1] == df[col2]) & (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] != 0) , (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] > df[col2]) , 
                      (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] < df[col2]) ,(df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] == 0)]

        choices = [50 , df[col2]/df[col1]*50,df[col2]/df[col1]* 25,100]

        condition = [(df[col2] != 0) , (df[col2] == 0)]
        choice = [100 , np.nan]

        if col0 is not None:
            conditions.insert(1, (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] == 0) & 
           (df[col0]!= 0))
            choices.insert(1, 25)

            condition.insert(0,(df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] != 0))
            choice.insert(0, 25)

        else:  
            condition.insert(0,(df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] != 0))
            choice.insert(0, 25)

        if col1 is None:
            conditions.insert(0, (df[col2] != 0))
            choices.insert(0, 100)
            conditions.insert(0, (df[col2] == 0))
            choices.insert(0, np.nan)



    df['comp{}'.format(i)] = np.select(conditions , choices , default = np.nan)
    df['comp{}'.format(i+1)] = np.select(condition , choice)


col_ref = None
col_prev = df.columns[0]
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns[1:], 1):
    build_comp(col,i, col_ref , col_prev)
    col_ref = col_prev
    col_prev = col
```

When I run this code , I am still not getting the comp column. This is what I am getting:

```
rule_id  col2  
50378     2     
51183     3
```

But I should get this as per my logic:

```
 rule_id  col2  comp1
50378     2     100
51183     3     100
```

I know there is something wrong with the `for loop` and `col_prev` logic but I don't know what.

Edit: For more simplification , this is how my `df` looks like:

[image]

This is my `df' looks like after applying my code:

[image]

But now suppose there is only one timestamp column is present such as this:

[image]

Then I want the result to be this:

```
date    2018-12-11 13:41:51  comp1
rule_id                        
51183         1                100
52368         1                100
```

Comment: Can you please provide an exact input file or set of inputs and the expected output for that input?  How is `df` created?  It looks like it is a global variable - is it?  Also, why iterate through the columns?  Not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Hi @user650654 , I have pivoted my data using `pivot_table()` method , taking some parts of the data and setting the columns and values. So , `df` stores that pivoted table which looks like the screenshot I just added. So I am performing comparisons between corresponding columns to get `comp` columns with the condition I have mentioned in my function. I will also add the screenshot of end result and a result if only one column is present too.

Comment: I have edited my question with the screenshot of my input file and the output file I want @user650654

Comment: In the case where the input has a single date column, the reason that there are no `comp` columns added is because `build_comp` is not even executed.  `col_prev` is set to the first (and only) column.  Then, `df.columns[1:]` evaluates to an empty list and the code inside the `for` loop is not executed.
I'm sorry, but I'm not able to understand what you're trying to do with the columns.  For the case where there is a single column, where does the question of previous and next columns arise?  You'll need to explain what you're trying to do in terms of the columns a bit more to understand this.

Comment: I needed the next and previous columns logic for a complex situation like, if there is a comparison between non-zero and 0 value , it should first check if the previous column has a non-zero value or not , if it does , then apply the `df[col2]/df[col1]` formula , otherwise `100`. So here, suppose,  `col1` is the column which has a non-zero value and  `col2` has zero value , then it checks if the previous column to `col1`, i.e `col0` has a non-zero value or not. Check the second row of my second image where values are `12 9 6 0`

Comment: If there is a single column present , I don't actually need to check the previous and next column but I was out of ideas so that's why I applied this function. If you could suggest something else where , with this `build_comp()` function, I can apply a condition where if there is only one column present and if it has a `non-zero` value , the comp column is created and it gives `100` value , otherwise `NaN` , then it would be great.

Comment: What I am trying to do with the columns is get a kind of a score by comparing one column with the adjacent one , so my conditions in the `build_comp()` column try to fulfill those conditions.

Comment: To handle the single column case, add an `if` statement as shown in my answer below.  Also, I would move the for loop and the if statement into the function itself and probably clean up the code a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `df` has a single column, the `for` loop gets skipped (i.e. the code in the loop does not get executed).

In order to add a column for the case where df has a single column, add the following code to the end:

```
if len(df.columns) == 1:
    df['comp1'] = [100] * len(df)
```

This assumes that `rule_id` is the row labels.  If not, then compare with 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Hi , appreciate your help. I forgot to mention that I am looping through various dataframes using `for loop`(I've made an edit to my question to include the whole code) and some of them contains more than one column which my `build_comp()` function takes care of. So when I am using this code on only 1 column dataframe, it is working fine but when I put it in for loop with other dataframes , it is changing my values created by `build_comp` function.

Comment: In the code `tx_id` is just a column with which I am grouping my data.

Comment: Nevermind. I got the result. I just modified the condition in your answer to `df['comp{}'.format(i)] = np.where(df == 0, np.nan , 100)` and got the desired result. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your condition about testing `col1 is None` is exactly the same as for `col0`; therefore, this is about setting a default value for `col1` so that it may not be provided.

Therefore, your code should be something like this:

```
def build_comp(col2, i, col0 = None, col1 = None):  # <== changing here

    if col1 is not None:  # we can compare <== EDITED HERE
        conditions = [(df[col1] == 0) & (df[col2] == 0),
                      (df[col1] == df[col2]),
                      (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] > df[col2]),
                      (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] < df[col2]),
                      (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] == 0)]

    choices = [np.nan,
               50,
               df[col2] / df[col1] * 50,
               df[col2] / df[col1] * 25,
               100]

    condition = [(df[col2] != 0),
                 (df[col2] == 0)]
    choice = [100,
              np.nan]

    if col0 is not None:
        conditions.insert(1, (df[col1] != 0) & (df[col2] == 0) & (df[col0] != 0))
        choices.insert(1, 50)

        condition.insert(0,(df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] != 0))
        choice.insert(0, 25)

    else:  # if col0 is None:  # <== use `else` instead of testing opposite
        condition.insert(0,(df[col2] != 0) & (df[col1] != 0))
        choice.insert(0, 25)

    df['comp{}'.format(i)] = np.select(conditions , choices , default = np.nan)
    df['comp{}'.format(i+1)] = np.select(condition , choice)
```

Beware, you use `choices` and `choice` for different stuff, that's not helping you.

Comment: Yeah , I have used condition and choice for the last column logic. Meaning , while comparing one column to another , when it reaches the last column , it gives the results mentioned by me in the condition.

Comment: Hi , I did what you said but now I am not getting any comp column. The part after the function and the for loop is still untouched. I am trying to figure it out how to change it , if you could give me a hint , it would be great

Comment: Hi, could you please edit your question above with a new section "current code" (or similar), with what you get after executing your code, and what you expect instead? That would greatly help.

Comment: I have edited my question with my recent code as per your request :)

Comment: Hi @Joël , I've edited my question with my code , the result I am getting and the result I want. Please take a look :)

Comment: Well, everything in your function should be able to handle the case where `col1 is None`, but it still contains code like `(df[col1]==0)`. Did you test this, to check its value? ;-)

Comment: Yes , you are right @ Joël . I removed the functionality of `(df[col1] == 0)` from my code but still the problem persists. Is there anything else wrong with my code?

Comment: Well, at first do you get any error message? And what do you think about inserting conditions implying `col1` only if `col1 is not None`, as you already did for `col0`? That way, only `col2` will be used if only `col2` is defined.

Comment: I am not getting any error message. And I tried setting `if col1 is not None` on the function `build_comp(col1 , col2 , i , col0 = None)` but it doesn't give me any result it just displays the same pivoted table , as if the condition doesn't even work.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is your code looking similar? If not, I must admit I'm lost here...

Comment: My code is same. Just after `if col1 is not None` , I added else which signifies `col1 is None` logic as: `conditions.insert(0, (df[col2] != 0))
                                      choices.insert(0, 100)
                                      conditions.insert(0, (df[col2] == 0))
                                      choices.insert(0, np.nan)`

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my `col_prev` and `for i, col in enumerate(df.columns[1:], 1):` logic. Can you please take a look at my question?

Comment: Hi , I just added `df['comp{}'.format(i)] = np.where(df == 0, np.nan , 100)` after my for loop and got the desire answer. Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score -1):

Why are You using None? 
IMO it`s better to use NaN.

Comment: Both are same , whether I use NaN or None , I am not getting the result.

Comment: `None` makes sense, as `col1` is a column name, not a table value. Said otherwise, it's a 'basic' Python variable.

Comment: I just vote -1, as your answer is about code style only, and does not try to help. Please consider revising your answer :)